# setting values of form in edit page is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state_name" value="<?php echo set_value('state_name',$rec_name->state_name);?>" >
```

I want to set the values in edit page.If I remove the values in text box.error want to display and value to be set.
by using this method error message is displaying but values not set

Comment: Please clarify your question. Right now I can't understand what you mean at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="state_name" value="<?php echo set_value('state_name')?>" id="state_name">
```